# TIMESTAMPDIFF MIN MAX optimization

Tags: mysql, join, query-performance

I have 3 Innodb tables 2 of which are "large"

- composer_sessions 92 rows
- sessions 2,530,587 rows
- tracking 8,032,697 rows

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                     MIN(tracking.timestamp),
                     MAX(tracking.timestamp) ) AS `thetime`,
       SUM(tracking.type = 'scene') AS `scenecount` 
FROM `tracking`, `sessions` 
WHERE tracking.tour_ID = '102098'
  AND sessions.session_ID = tracking.session_ID 
  AND sessions.IP NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT `IP`
                          FROM `composer_sessions`)
GROUP BY tracking.session_ID
HAVING TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(tracking.timestamp), 
                             MAX(tracking.timestamp)) <= '3600'
   AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(tracking.timestamp),
                             MAX(tracking.timestamp) ) > '60'
   AND SUM(tracking.type = 'scene') >= '2'
```

All of the columns used in the query are indexed.
The "join" in the query is used to weed out data associated with IP addresses we don't want in the results.

Is there a better way for me to structure this query and/or can anyone suggest compound(multi-column) indexes to make this query run faster?

Comment: Try using `thetime` in the `HAVING` clause, instead of repeating the calculation. I'm not sure if it will make a difference, though.

Comment: Try replacing the `NOT IN` test with a `LEFT JOIN/NULL` pattern.

Comment: You may want to read this, especially the section on questions about query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables.  "All of the columns used in the query are indexed" is too imprecise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting your query to use modern join syntax, to say

```
SELECT ...
  FROM tracking
  JOIN sessions ON sessions.session_ID = tracking.session_ID
  LEFT JOIN composer_sessions ON sessions.IP = composer_sessions.IP
 WHERE composer_sessions.IP IS NULL
   AND tracking.tour_ID = '102098'
 GROUP BY tracking.session_ID
HAVING ...
```

This also uses the `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` pattern to eliminate the unwanted rows based on the contents of your third table.

Then, create a so-called [compound covering index](https://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727) on your `tracking` table. It should contain the following columns in this order.

```
    ( tour_id, session_id, timestamp, type )
```

This allows the `tracking` part of your query to be satisfied directly from the index. The query planner can random-access the index based on your choice of `tour_id` because that value is left-most in the index. It can then scan the index sequentially to pull out the rest of the stuff you need.

Similarly, try a compound index on your `sessions` table on

```
   ( session_ID, IP )
```

and see if it helps. You can also try putting those columns in the opposite order.

Be aware that lots of indexes on individual columns rarely help the performance of complex queries. You need well-chosen compound indexes for that. Lots of single-column indexes are often considered harmful to overall performance, because they slow down inserts and updates and offer no benefit.

Read this:  http://use-the-index-luke.com/